# sending message to multiple users using php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need help. I'm trying to send a message to multiple users or you might call recipients. So far the code below works to send a message to one recipients only. I want to use a regular form where the usernames name can be separated by a comma and than a message or messages can be sent to all the users while being stored in a mysql database. Its a database based email system and not a send to a different e-mail address system.

I have gotten commas to separate the usernames inside the username field using jquery but than i get stuck after that and that simple jquery is not included inside the codes below as i'm not sure how it would even work with it.

let me ask a simpler question as I am not understanding the explode and for each. Lets pretend I wanted to send out a message to multiple members using the id2 as recipients while adding information in the message, who and what field. How would I do it would I do it.

```
 mysql_query('insert into pm (id, id2, title,  who, what, user1, user2, message, timestamp, user1read,    user2read)values("'.$id.'", "1", "'.$title.'",   "'.$who.'",  "'.$what.'", "'.$_SESSION['id'].'", "'.$dn1['recipid'].'", "'.$message.'", "'.time().'", "yes", "no")')
```

Tried this but it still only sends message to one user.

Comment: Explode the comma separated list of names/emails whatever you are using and simply loop them

Comment: I did try doing this but nothing happened and no data went in. I also tried using for each. Maybe i did in a wrong way.

Comment: Since it didn't work, I'll bet that's right. And if you post what you tried, we can probably tell you what you did wrong. Also, please try to post properly indented code -- give your readers a fighting chance to understand the structure.

Comment: You have a better chance to get a good answer if you post only relevant code.

Comment: thanks for everyone that tried to answer it; however, people who don't know the answer should not be voting my question down as if I said i knew the answer.

Comment: **WOW SOMETHING SO SIMPLE AND NO ONE HAS AN ANSWER. COME ON ITS NOT LIKE I'm asking such a hard question**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both explode and foreach:

```
$recipients = explode(',',$recip);
foreach ($recipients as $r) {
    //We check if the recipient exists
    $dn1 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(id) as recip, id as recipid, (select count(*) from pm) as npm from header where username="'.$r.'"'));
        if($dn1['recip']==1)

                 echo 'recip exists';



        else
        {
       //Otherwise, we say the recipient does not exists
       $error = 'The recipient does not exists.';

        }
}
```

Comment: oh thanks. I wasn't trying to explode the show if recipients exists query but insert it into the database using the msysql query below it. Would I still add for each and would it be  for each id2 as id2. user 1 and user 2 in the mysql query is suppose to be for the read section only. Id2 is suppose to stand for the users receiving the info. I really don't need to include check recipients query.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Yes you would still use explode and foreach if you want to run through a loop of recipients that are stored in one field and separated by commas. However, you don't need to use these methods for inserting into the database as I presume you want to add one record per message sent but the recipients as comma separated values in the id2 field. However, at the moment, I have no idea why you are trying to use jquery as it seems to have no purpose for your requirements and I don't know where you are assigning values to $id2 before you are using is in your explode function.

Comment: yeah i figured i was exploding the wrong id it was suppose to id not id2.

Answer (score 1):

**You will need to restructure your database** to allow sending messages to multiple users. There's no other way to do it.

One ID field should not be used to store multiple recipient IDs - you're bound to run into problems sooner or later (I suppose you already have :) ).

Here's how I would structure your tables (I'm assuming recipients and senders are all registered users on your system):

- Message table: Message ID, Sender ID, Send date/time, Subject, Message, Attachments, etc.
- Message recipients table: Message ID, Recipient ID (single recipient only!), Status (i.e. is it read/unread)

You would have to store each individual recipient in the "Message recipients" table separately and link it to the "Message" table via the Message ID.

Hope this helps.